# How to remove .aspx from url

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i remove .aspx from my urls as I used UrlRewritingNet and its giving me page not found error when i host the site to the server but its alright in the IDE browser.

Comment: This problem is usually caused by IIS not passing the request to the asp.net pipeline. You can change this behavior by adding a wildcard mapping in IIS, although this will probably have a negative performance effect when serving static files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell IIS to let ASP.NET handle all requests. This is known as a wildcard mapping, see option 1 on the following link: http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS 7 then you need to use Classic asp.net pool, which supports UrlRewritingNet.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, in tghe settings for your project. Click on **Home Directory**, then **configuration**, then **mappings**. Find .aspx, click settings, uncheck "**Check that file exists**".

Um, thats for IIS 6, so getting to the setting is probably a bit different in 7 but it's still there.